# How can I bind a value to sap.m.Text in XML view with condition?

Tags: sapui5

I want to bind a value to the value of a Text control with condition.

For eg: my json is

```
[{
    "name": "XXXXX",
    "active": false
}, {
    "name": "YYYY",
    "active": true
}]
```

**MyFile.view.xml**

```
<tbl:Table id="details">
    <tbl:Column width="11rem">
        <Label text="Name" />
        <tbl:template>
            <Text text="{name}"/>
        </tbl:template>
    </tbl:Column>
    <tbl:Column width="11rem">
        <Label text="Status" />
        <tbl:template>
            <Text text="{active}"/>
        </tbl:template>
    </tbl:Column>
</tbl:Table>
```

Here i'm getting UI as Table

```
Name   Status
XXXX   false
YYYY   true
```

But I want to show output as below

```
Name   Status
XXXX   InActive
YYYY   Active
```

How can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either use a [formatter](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/0f8626ed7b7542ffaa44601828db20de.html) or [expression binding](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/guide/daf6852a04b44d118963968a1239d2c0.html). Expression binding would look like this:

```
<Text text="{= ${active} === true ? 'Active' : 'Inactive'}"/>
```